# Need help understanding mySQL PHP project

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I was given an assinment to finish a project from an advanced Web Aplication student and im trying to understand all the code, but it is becoming very difficult. I'd appreciate some help with the code lines. Im already commenting the lines to help me advance. Can you comment the lines as well so I can advance in the code? Thanks for all the cooperation in advance. Its merely a challenge so no pressure for anyone, i just ask for good will kind of help. Code is in portuguese, hope it doesnt make much difference, if so, i'll clarify it.

(Code verified)

```
<?php

require_once("top.php"); //incluir ficheiro uma única vez

$idvoo= !empty($_GET["idvoo"]) ? $_GET["idvoo"] : null; //verifica se a variável existe ou retorna valor nulo

$query= "select a.ID, a.TotalFilas, a.LugaresPorFila_Esquerda,".
" a.LugaresPorfila_Central, a.LugaresPorFila_Direita FROM aviao as a".
" WHERE a.ID = (SELECT v.IDAviao FROM voo as v WHERE v.ID = ?)" ; //Consulta os parâmetros especificados no código da 
                                                              //respectiva tabela (aviao)
 //echo $query;
 //die;

$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query); //Prepara a consulta para a base de dados
//var_dump($mydb->error);


$stmt->bind_param("i", $idvoo); //Muda o valor do parãmetro "?" para "idvoo"

$stmt->execute();               //Executa o mysql


$result = $stmt->get_result();  //Obtem os resultados
$aviao = $result->fetch_assoc();//Cria um array associativo do resultado mysql

//var_dump($aviao);
```

Thank you all for your answers, they were extremely fast and I could understand a lot more of the code besause of them. Specially the statement query which i had never used before. If you still have the time I have more lines of code I need to understand, no need to comment on repeated statements such as "$stmt" "query" etc.

```
echo "<h1>Lugares</h1>";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>Fila</th>"; //Construção da Tabela Lugares

$letras = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I');//Criação de um array com as letras relativas a cada linha de lugares

$posicao = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < $aviao['LugaresPorFila_Esquerda']; $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".$letras[$posicao]."</th>";
    $posicao++;
}
for ($i=0; $i < $aviao['LugaresPorfila_Central']; $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".$letras[$posicao]."</th>";
    $posicao++;
}
for ($i=0; $i < $aviao['LugaresPorFila_Direita']; $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".$letras[$posicao]."</th>";
    $posicao++;
}

echo "</tr>";

//Consulta os parâmetros especificados no código da tabela bilhete
$query= "select b.ID, b.IDVoo, b.NumFila, b.LetraLugar,".
" b.Estado, v.ID as IDVoo FROM bilhete as b 
INNER JOIN voo as v ".
" ON b.IDVoo = v.ID".                                               
" WHERE ((b.IDVoo=?) OR (? is NULL)) AND (b.Estado='L') ORDER BY b.NumFila, b.LetraLugar" ;

$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query);



$stmt->bind_param("ii", $idvoo,$idvoo);

$stmt->execute();


$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Bilhete Nº:</th>";
        echo "<th>Fila:</th>";
        echo "<th>Lugar:</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
while ($bilhete = $result->fetch_assoc()){


    //if ($bilhete["Estado"] == "L") {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td class="form-control"><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"     href="carrinho.php?id='.$bilhete["ID"].'">  Adicionar </a></td>';
        echo "<td>" .$bilhete["NumFila"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$bilhete["LetraLugar"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
//  }

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What Do You Want To Know About This Code?

Comment: Also, see JOINs in mysql.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ Thank you I did check this website, and it was pretty helpful to understand JOINs and more of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code commented further.

```
//Require another File
require_once("top.php");

//Check if the Get Variable Exists else give it a value of null
$idvoo= !empty($_GET["idvoo"]) ? $_GET["idvoo"] : null;

//Create a Mysql Query for the database
$query= "select a.ID, a.TotalFilas, a.LugaresPorFila_Esquerda,".
" a.LugaresPorfila_Central, a.LugaresPorFila_Direita FROM aviao as a".
" WHERE a.ID = (SELECT v.IDAviao FROM voo as v WHERE v.ID = ?)" ;




//Prepare to query the database
$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query);

//Change the ? in the query to $idvoo declared earlier
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idvoo);

//Execute the MySQL
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch the results of the query
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 

//Create an associative array with the result
$aviao = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Set up a table with three columns (th being column header)
echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
          echo "<th>Bilhete Nº:</th>";
          echo "<th>Fila:</th>";
          echo "<th>Lugar:</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

    //While we have results from the database lets loop through them one by one
    while ($bilhete = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {


        //if ($bilhete["Estado"] == "L") {
        //Foreach result we have, create a new row and insert the values into the relevant columns. The first column will be a link that will pass the ID to another page for processing again using a $_GET variable
        echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td class="form-control"><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"     href="carrinho.php?id='.$bilhete["ID"].'">  Adicionar </a></td>';
            echo "<td>" .$bilhete["NumFila"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>" .$bilhete["LetraLugar"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
       // }

    }
  //Now we have looped through the results, close the table element. If there were no results we would simply see a table with heading and no rows of information
  echo "</table>";
```

Quite simply you are retrieving rows from the database based on the value of a `$_GET` variable. So try to navigate to your script like so:

```
http://url-to-script?idvoo=1
http://url-to-script?idvoo=2
```

This means that the value of `$_GET['idvoo']` is 1 in the first example and 2 in the second. If you do not put the get parameter in the URL, the `id` it will check will be null, as can be seen by this line:

```
$idvoo= !empty($_GET["idvoo"]) ? $_GET["idvoo"] : null;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, they were extremely fast and I could understand a lot more of the code besause of them. Specially the statement query which i had never used before. If you still have the time I have more lines of code I need to understand, no need to comment on repeated statements such as "$stmt" "query" etc. Altough I could not check the rows in the script through the url, just in mysql database

Comment: @angelfmf I have added the remaining code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once("top.php"); // included a file

$idvoo= !empty($_GET["idvoo"]) ? $_GET["idvoo"] : null; // Assigned the value to $idvoo
$query= "select a.ID, a.TotalFilas, a.LugaresPorFila_Esquerda,".
" a.LugaresPorfila_Central, a.LugaresPorFila_Direita FROM aviao as a".
" WHERE a.ID = (SELECT v.IDAviao FROM voo as v WHERE v.ID = ?)" ; // Constructed SQL query.
//echo $query;
//die;

$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query); // Prepared SQL statement.
//var_dump($mydb->error);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idvoo); // Bound parameter $idvoo to the question mark in query 'WHERE v.ID = ?)'
$stmt->execute(); // Executed the SQL statement so that we get results.
$result = $stmt->get_result();  // Get results from Database
$aviao = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Fetch associative array for the result set from SQL.
//var_dump($aviao);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once("top.php"); //The statement compels the page to be run in presence of this top.php i.e. top.php must be available in the page

$idvoo= !empty($_GET["idvoo"]) ? $_GET["idvoo"] : null; //it states that if GET variable idvoo is not empty then idvoo variable will be assign a value of the same and in opposite a null value will be assigned.

$query= "select a.ID, a.TotalFilas, a.LugaresPorFila_Esquerda,".
" a.LugaresPorfila_Central, a.LugaresPorFila_Direita FROM aviao as a".
" WHERE a.ID = (SELECT v.IDAviao FROM voo as v WHERE v.ID = ?)" ;//The above query states that select some fields from table aviao with respect to selection of v.IDAviao from another table voo 
$stmt = $mydb->prepare($query);`//preparing the query..using PDO
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idvoo);//Binding the parameter to variable name..read [this][1] 

$stmt->execute();//Executing the query
`$result = $stmt->get_result(); //Getting the result



`$aviao = $result->fetch_assoc();`//storing in associative array.
//var_dump($aviao);
```